# Read 4,000,000,000 lines from a file and save into an array in C

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, out-of-memory

I need to read 4,000,000,000 lines from a file and save them into an array.

But the Linux kernel kill the process because of out of memory:

```
tail /var/log/kern.log
... Out of memory: Kill process ...
```

## The code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main() {

    /*
     * Read line by line from the file and write into the array
     */ 

    int lines_allocated = 128;
    int max_line_len = 15;

    char **array = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char*)*lines_allocated);
    if (array==NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Out of memory (1).\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    file = fopen("file", "r");
    if (file == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Error opening file.\n");
        exit(2);
    }

    int il;
    for (il=0;1;il++) {
        int j;

        /* Have we gone over our line allocation? */
        if (il >= lines_allocated) {
            int new_size;

            /* Double our allocation and re-allocate */
            new_size = lines_allocated*2;
            array = (char **)realloc(array,sizeof(char*)*new_size);
            if (array==NULL){
                fprintf(stderr,"Out of memory.\n");
                exit(3);
            }
            lines_allocated = new_size;
        }

        /* Allocate space for the next line */
        array[il] = malloc(max_line_len);
        if (array[il]==NULL)
            {
            fprintf(stderr,"Out of memory (3).\n");
            exit(4);
            }
        if (fgets(array[il], max_line_len-1, file)==NULL)
            break;

        /* Get rid of CR or LF at end of line */
        for (j=strlen(array[il])-1;j>=0 && (array[il][j]=='\n' || array[il][j]=='\r');j--)
            ;

        array[il][j+1]='\0';
    }

    /* Close login file */
    fclose(file);

    /* Print the array of data from the file */
    for (i=0; i < il; i++)
        printf("%s\n", array[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

What is the most appropriate and effective way to do this? Maybe read first block, done with it, then read next block and so on?

What are the solutions of this issue?

Comment: read it after smaller blocks of lines.

Comment: As you said , you may read 1 line at a time , process it and then do same for remaining lines of data.

Comment: You answered yourself. Piece by piece is the right way

Comment: Do you need to process ***all*** of the data simultaneously? Or sequentially? If you can process it sequentially then read and process one line at a time. Otherwise read it in blocks. Or you could [memory map the whole or part of the file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_file).

Comment: You also seem to be calling malloc, once per line.  Why not get the size of the file, malloc once for the whole thing, and look through the memory for where the line starts are, then process it.

Comment: The "most appropriate way" depends on what you are going to do with that data. Give us a little more context.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you would read one `byte` from each line you would need 29GB of memory.

For such huge data it's crucial to load as small amount of data as possible and then after processing is over freeing the memory. Otherwise you'll miss memory.

Comment: Why "as small amount of data as possible"? I would personally get a nice, fat fixed size buffer (but not too fat) and read in large chunks (but not gigabyte sized). Then I would read line for line from that fat buffer. No need to malloc and free each time.

Comment: What about memory mapped file?

Answer (score 1):

The obvious solution is to process the input in blocks. If you can do this, this has the added benefit that you can do computation (on the current block) while I/O is in progress (most OSes do lookahead buffering), leading to shorter real world time taken compared to first reading all data, then processing it in one chunk.

(I often mention that fact for those who are implementing a `sort` -type utility. For real, human-measurable speedups, you should read the inputs into a tree, rather than into an array and then sort the array, because storage is slow, and inserting each input record (line) immediately into a tree essentially allows you to use the time otherwise spent in waiting for I/O to sort the data. It may use a tiny bit more CPU time (depending on your tree implementation) compared to a really good array sort algorithm, but humans do not often care much about that. We mostly care about real world time spent waiting. We don't like to wait.)

---

If the input records (lines) are accessed at random, and you work on a 64-bit architecture, memory mapping techniques may make it *possible*. (If you *can* do the work in chunks, do so; if you cannot, memory mapping lets you do the processing even when you don't have sufficient RAM.)

Years ago, I wrote a minimal example on how to use a file-backed sparse memory map in 64-bit Linux to [manipulate a terabyte data structure](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/data-type-in-c-to-hold-tetrabyte-875026/#post4324888).

In this case, you can use a read-only memory map for random access to the text file. Note that in Linux, you should use [`mmap(NULL, aligned_length, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED | MAP_NORESERVE, fd, 0)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) where `aligned_length` is the length of the text file rounded up to next multiple of `sysconf(SC_PAGESIZE)`. Such mappings do not use swap (and therefore the amount of swap space does not limit the size of the mapping), but the kernel can and will drop the pages (and reread when needed from the file itself) if memory is too tight.

A second memory mapping can be used to store the offsets (on 64-bit architectures, `size_t` is sufficiently large) to the beginning of each line. This mapping should use `mmap(NULL, offbufsize, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_NORESERVE, fd2, 0)`, where `offbufsize` is a multiple of `sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE)`, but at least as large as the number of lines in the input file, multiplied by `sizeof (size_t)`.

Determining the beginning of each line is an operation best done in chunks (of say 512×1024 = 524288 bytes). That is, you should first set up the second mapping, using `ftruncate()` and `mremap()` to grow it when necessary, reading the first file using low-level I/O (unistd.h `read()`) in abovementioned chunks to determine the beginning of each line.

I personally have done something similar in practice. Even with universal newline support (that supports `\r\n` or CRLF, `\n\r` or LFCR, `\r` or CR, and `\n` or LF, at the same time, automatically) you only need a few extra bytes of storage in the array used to store the chunk read from the large text file. Because the initial pass is completely linear, using `posix_fadvise(fd,0,0,POSIX_FADV_NOREUSE)` or `posix_fadvise(fd,0,0,POSIX_FADV_SEQUENTIAL)` may be warranted.

Given at least a couple of gigabytes of RAM available for buffering (which is considered a typical situation even on smallish 64-bit Linux/POSIX workstations), even though the Linux kernel paging stuff is not "magic", it works surprisingly well.

The most common reason for unsatisfactory performance with much-larger-than-available-RAM mappings I've seen in Linux, is forgetting the `MAP_NORESERVE` flag. This causes unnecessary limitations (available swap space limiting the maximum allowed mapping size), as well as poor performance when memory is tight (because the pages are *written to swap*, instead of just dropped to the floor).